# Get 2 or more keyboard layout indicators in XFCE

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, keyboard-layout, xfce, indicator

I am using 2 monitors and have 2 panels for each one in XFCE 4.12. I want to have a keyboard indicator on each panel but it seems that I can have only one instance.

[image]

Add button disabled. Indicator plugin is  xfce4-xkb-plugin 0.7.1-2.

How to get 2 or more keyboard layout indicators? May be other plugin, which one?